# .net7.0 Windows platform calling ChannelFactory get exception System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'Operation is not supported on this platform.'

Tags: exception, wcf, channelfactory

I have a simple windows console application where I try to connect to WCF service. I have trouble with following code.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <StartupObject>ConsoleApp_net7.Program</StartupObject>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Primitives" Version="6.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

There is simple code :

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApp_net7
{
    internal class Program
    {

        private static string serviceUrl = "http://10.240.58.103/iProfits2.GatewayServiceVERSIONING/ProfitsGateway.asmx";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
            {
                // Windows-specific code.
                var _channel = new ChannelFactory<IProfitsGateway>(serviceUrl);
            }
            else if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))
            {
                // Linux-specific code
            }

            //_getaway = new ProfitsGatewayUserLogin(serviceUrl);
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
        }
    }

    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "iProfits")]
    [XmlSerializerFormat]
    public interface IProfitsGateway
    {
        [OperationContract(Action = "iProfits/UserInformations", ReplyAction = "*")]
        UserInformationsExport UserInformations(UserInformationsImport import, ExecutionParameters executionParameters);
    }
}
```

And when I hit ChannelFactory I get exception :

System.PlatformNotSupportedException
HResult=0x80131539
Message=Operation is not supported on this platform.
Source=System.ServiceModel.Primitives
StackTrace:
at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.InitializeEndpoint(String configurationName, EndpointAddress address)
at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory'1..ctor(String endpointConfigurationName, EndpointAddress remoteAddress)
at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory'1..ctor(String endpointConfigurationName)
at ConsoleApp_net7.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\ProjectsNC\Inhouse .NET Projects\IntrasoftLogin\Test\ConsoleApp_net7\Program.cs:line 19

Answer (score 0):

I take a look at Microsoft Source code and found the reason.

It seems the `configurationName` not support any more.
Since, as I believe, the `.config` file is not supported and the `configurationName` has no meaning now.

[image: ExceptionHelper.PlatformNotSupported]